# Creating a vector of threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am new to using threads in `c++` and I am trying to make a vector of threads that will all run the same function with the following signature:

```
std::vector<int> sliceComputation(SquareMatrix A, std::vector<int> B)
```

I keep getting these two errors though:

> threads.cpp:10:26: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::thread'
>      `threadPool.push_back(std::thread(sliceComputation, A, slice));`

and

> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:1574:36: error: calling a private constructor of class 'std::__1::thread'
>                   `::new ((void*)__p) _Tp(__a0);`

Code:

```
 std::vector<std::thread> threadPool;

 std::vector<int> slice = B.getSliceOfMatrix(1);

 for(int i = 0; i < numOfThreads; i++)
 {

   threadPool.push_back(std::thread(sliceComputation, A, slice));

 }
```

How can I create a vector of threads in C++ ?

Comment: `std::thread` isn't copyable, you need to use `std::vector<T>::emplace_back()`.

Comment: Consider using `async` function instead of `thread` class. Your thread function `sliceComputation` returns data - `vector<int>`, how do you want to access this result with `std::thread` api?